# Using multiple Tomcat Container Provided Filters (Remote Address Filter)

Tags: tomcat, filter, localhost, remote-access

I am trying to restrict what URLs can be accessed on my tomcat server based on IP address. What I am trying to do is allow access to everywhere when tomcat is accessed via loopback addresses (i.e. localhost) and only allow access to certain areas for all other remote IPs.  I have the following two filters in conf/web.xml but they are not behaving as I would like.  Right now *all* remote access is being denied (not what I want) and *all* local access is being allowed (what I want).  I can't get tomcat to allow all IP addresses to access /terms/*, /help/*, etc.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- ================== Built In Filter Definitions ===================== -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>Restrict Remote Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name> 
        <param-value>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+</param-value>  <!-- for any IP address, * not allowed here -->
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Restrict Remote Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/terms/*, /help/*, /messagebroker/*</url-pattern>  <!-- allow access to these areas only -->
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Allow Localhost Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name> 
        <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>  <!-- for localhost access… -->
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Allow Localhost Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  <!-- access all areas -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<url-pattern>/terms/*, /help/*, /messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
```

try separate url-pattern for each pattern, as far as I know, character "," (comma) is not recognized as special character, but a part of your url. Try this:

```
<url-pattern>/terms/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/help/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
```